# Downloading big file (54MB) from Jenkins installation with apache FileUtils only downloads 9% of it

Tags: java, jenkins

I am trying to download a fat jar (54MB) from Jenkins using Apache commons IO.
Codewise i think i am doing the right thing, but unexteptedly, the dowloaded file is only 4.5MB.
My code:

```
File dumpFile = new File(local_file_location);
FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(remoteURL), dumpFile, 300000, 300000);
```

Any advice? am i missing some option?

Comment: Is it possible that the server is compressing the file, and FileUtils isn't decompressing it?

Comment: Thanks, the server is a Jenkins installation, i dont know what is the default behavior, i would have to look into that

Comment: @CardinalSystem when i try to open the downloaded file, winRar tells me indeed that it is corrupted

Comment: Did you try downloading the file from your browser? Did it work?

Comment: @CardinalSystem it works but i it pauses at 30MB, i have to resume it and only then it downloads the whole file

Comment: Are you perhaps downloading the HTML download page instead of the file?

Comment: @user207421 no, in the corrupted file i see part of the jar content

Comment: Jenkins is only serving me the first chunk, i need to find a way to tell Jenkins to give me the whole thing

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it like this:

```
  private File downloadFromJenkins(String stringUrl) throws IOException {
    String[] jarParts = stringUrl.split("/");
    String jarDump = Util.addTrailingSlash(config.getJarsTmpStorage()) + jarParts[jarParts.length - 1];
    File dumpFile = new File(jarDump);

    logger.info("Downloading jar {} \n to: {}", stringUrl, jarDump);
    URL website = new URL(stringUrl);
    URLConnection connection = website.openConnection();
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(connection.getInputStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dumpFile);
    long expectedSize = connection.getContentLength();
    logger.info("Expected size: {}", expectedSize);
    long transferedSize = 0L;
    while (transferedSize < expectedSize) {
      transferedSize +=
          fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, transferedSize, 1 << 24);
      logger.info( "{} bytes received", transferedSize);
    }
    fos.close();
    return dumpFile;
  }
```

Comment: This is what is called a "code only answer", they are not acceptable on Stack Overflow. Add an explanation if you can.

Comment: @Gimby i actually see hundreds of this kind of answer, they usually go like “try this”. And i think that you are right in case of complex code structure, but anyone working in software development should be anle to understand what is happening in the simple snippet i posted